# Find x values based on y value from panda and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out how to get x values based on y value from panda data series and matplolib.

To be more precise I need to get x value when y=0.5 from multiple columns. The data is normalized and cut according to user inputs.

I don't have enough data points to get precise 0.5 value (the nearest might be 0.4 or 0.6)

I though maybe it is possible to draw line at 0.5 value and get intersection points or somehow interpolate data, but I do not realy know how to do it properly.

Maybe someone has some suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, sep=',' )  

colnames = list(df.columns)
print(colnames)
colnames.pop(0)
for i in colnames:

df[i]= (df[i] - df[i].min()) / (df[i].max() - df[i].min())



print(df)
df.plot(x='Temperature')
plt.show()

y = input('Enter temperature')
d1 = df[df['Temperature'] >= int(y)]
a = input('Second temperature')
d2 = d1[d1['Temperature'] <= int(a)]

colnames2 = list(d2.columns)
for i in colnames2:
df[i] = (df[i] - df[i].min()) / (df[i].max() - df[i].min())
main = d2.plot(x='Temperature')
line = plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='black', linestyle='-')

plt.show()

p1 = d2.interpolate()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I realised you're trying to predict x from y, not y from x, so I've swapped my variables around below. The problem is similar.**

The best way of doing this depends on what the data relates to, how it is distributed, etc. However, one approach would be to train a linear model based on the data and then use the model to estimate the value of x when y equals 0.5.

For example, you could use one of the linear models offered by scikit-learn:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = """y,x
0.1,4
0.2,8
0.3,12
0.4,16
0.6,24
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

x = df[['x']]
y = df[['y']]

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the available data
regr.fit(y, x)

# Predict for the missing value
interpolated = regr.predict(np.array([[0.5]]))

print(float(interpolated))
```

...or you can fit a more sophisticated model based on what your data is like.

Comment: Thanks, my model is not linear, but do you think it would be better if I would try to fit my data (Boltzman should do the trick) and get value from fit?

Comment: That seems as sensible as anything! Another plan is to take the two Y values nearest to the one you are trying to interpolate and taking the average of those. This would be suitable for nonlinear data as long as the Y values you have are sufficiently near the one you're trying to interpolate.

Comment: Great, I was also thinking about taking two data points. I will look into.